# Running explorer.exe I% via OS shell results in hanging process

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-server-2008-r2

Running "explorer.exe" via command prompt / OS shell will result in File Explorer opening as expected.

However, when adding an argument (e.g. "explorer.exe C:\"), File Explorer will not open - instead, an explorer.exe process **will** initiate (it tends to stay at around 4-6MB and then will terminate after a short period).

Opening File Explorer manually and opening C:\ works as expected.

There appears to be a service / restriction in place that's stalling the process? I'm just not sure how to pinpoint it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you just tried `explorer c:`? Both ways worked on my PC (Win7Pro x64 SP1) which is the same code for '08R2 I believe. Anyway I'm guessing its trying to interrupt the backslash as something else & fails. Here are some links that may help (I just skimmed them):

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152457
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/130510
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307856
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314853